# Getting day of the week in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've come across a problem I've not been able to solve. I have a log which regularly needs updating with today's date in a specific format. I've attempted to write a script to do so but essentially what I would like is to assign a keyboard shortcut, but going into a menu would be acceptable. What I need is today's date in the format

### Tuesday - 16/01/2018

The script I've got currently includes the line

```
var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "###  - dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This gets me almost everything I need, but after the #s I'd like the day of the week. I can see a few functions that apply to sheets, that work there, but how would I get this working in docs?

And assuming I manage that this is currently assigned to a custom UI menu, is it also possible to hook this up to a macro/keyboard shortcut?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change format slightly and use `EEEE` which will print day of a week:

```
var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "### EEEE - dd/MM/yyyy")
```

The code above has output `### Tuesday - 16/01/2018`
You can find all available format options below:
[image]
Reference to documentation for time formatting: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/form-publisher/documentation/form-and-template-edition/date-and-time-settings#TOC-Hours-and-Minutes

Comment: Brilliant! exactly what I needed.